# Error module 'keras.optimizers' has no attribute 'RMSprop'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am running this code below and it returned an error AttributeError: module 'keras.optimizers' has no attribute 'RMSprop'. I download tensorflow using `pip install tensorflow`.

```
from keras import layers
from keras import models

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu',
                        input_shape=(150, 150, 3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.summary()

from keras import optimizers

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=1e-4), metrics=['acc'])
```

Could anyone please help explain to me what's wrong with this? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you trying importing from tensorflow and not from keras, i.e. ‘from tensorflow.keras import optimizers’?

Comment: How exactly did you install keras? And note that you are using keras, not tf.keras. Your keras installation is somehow broken, which version was installed?

Comment: @Daniel Lenz I have tried import from tensorflow and run the code again but I got the error, ValueError: Could not interpret optimizer identifier: <tensorflow.python.keras.optimizer_v2.rmsprop.RMSprop object at 0x0000029743653820>

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I installed my keras through tensorflow with ```pip install tensorflow```. My keras is under version '2.5.0'.

Comment: pip install tensorflow does not install keras, it installs tf.keras,  that is why I made the clarification in my first comment. You should downgrade keras to versions 2.4.x

Comment: Actually I have got it working now by using the code ```from tensorflow.keras import optimizers```. I am not sure why it didn't work before. Thank you for you guys' suggestions!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As you said, you installed tensorflow (which includes keras) via `pip install tensorflow`, and not keras directly. Installing keras via `pip install keras` is not recommended anymore (see also the instructions [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras#installation)).

This means that keras is available through `tensorflow.keras`. Instead of importing via `from keras import optimizers`, you should use `from tensorflow.keras import optimizers`.

Answer (score 5):

You should instead write:

```
from tensorflow import keras
from keras import optimizers
optimizer=keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=0.01)
```

Comment: I am sure it would help the community if you explained to us why your code would solve the OP's problem

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same error, and I avoid it by importing optimizers
like that :

```
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
```

then I applied the RMSprop :

```
optimisers.RMSprop(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

It works

```
from keras.optimizers import rmsprop_v2
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop')
```

but I don't know why..

Answer (score 0):

```
import tensorflow
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
optimizer = tensorflow.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.0003,decay=1e-6)
```

note `RMSprop` vs `rmsprop`